# Bluemix devops insight: Integration with sonarQube

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-cloud-tools, devops-services, devops-insights

I have started using Bluemix devops insights service available as part of Bluemix toolchain. I am not able to see any documentation on integration of SonarQube with the tool. The one available in the service is a bit misleading as it only talks about UT, code cov. & FVT but not on how to publish SonarQube static code analysis reports to Devops insight, can someone pl. help?

Answer (score 0):

Check the documentation pages on [Publishing Test Results](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/DevOpsInsights/risk_cd.html#configure_pipeline_jobs).  If you're using DevOps Pipelines, go into the scripts for your builds, and integrate in the [idra](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-idra3) command as shown in the example.  Also spend some time reading that npm package, which goes over how to do this within a Continuous delivery pipeline, or from the CLI.